# Custom radio group with a label in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, radio-group

I am trying to create a custom radio group where I can add a label on top via an attribute (the sample below has a hardcoded label text, I did not include the attribute in this sample to keep things simple).

I currently have this code for the radio group:

```
class LabelRadioGroup(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : RadioGroup(context, attrs)
{
    init 
    {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.compound_label_radiogroup, this, true)
    }
}
```

And this xml (compound_label_radiogroup):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label" />

    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Usage is like this:

```
 <sample.LabelRadioGroup
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Radio button 1"/>
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
              android:text="Radio button 2"/>
</sample.LabelRadioGroup>
```

The current code is definitely wrong, and adding a 'RadioGroup' in the LinearLayout doesn't look right. But I can't figure out how to do it in another way.

Right now the label is showing in front of the radio buttons. I would like the end result to be a reusable radio group that looks like this:

Label

O Radio button 1   O Radio button 2

To clarify, it needs to be reusable, so depending on usage the radio buttons in the group could be different. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't have time to play around with it, but I think the problem is that a `RadioGroup` **is** a `LinearLayout` - so when you construct your custom view (which is a `RadioGroup`) and inflate `compound_label_radiogroup.xml`, you're adding *another* `LinearLayout` *inside* the first one. Then when you use your custom view in XML, you're adding `RadioButton`s inside it, which go inside *the outer `RadioGroup`* `LinearLayout` as siblings of your inflated LL (run it and check the Layout Inspector, that'll be clearer!)

Comment: Since you want to be able to use your custom view *as* a `RadioGroup` the normal way, sticking buttons inside it, you don't want to have a separate `RadioGroup` inflated inside it, and write code to basically move all `View`s added to the custom view inside that internal second `RadioGroup`, if that makes sense. You just want them in your custom view itself, which is a `RadioGroup` - all you really want is to add a `TextView` to the base implementation, right? It's probably easier to just use `addView` in code, and create or inflate a `TextView` to get the object you want to add to the layout

Comment: @cactustictacs You are absolutely right. The only issue I'm having with this now is that it's putting the label in front of the textboxes (since the RadioGroup needs a horizontal alignment for the RadioButtons), but it needs to go on top.

Comment: Ah right yeah, hmm. That seems like a no-go then! I haven't really messed with this side of custom/compound views (creating something that acts as a `ViewGroup` so you can nest things in it in XML) but you could possibly do your original approach, and move all the added child views into your internal `RadioGroup`, and set its orientation to whatever was set on your custom view. Honestly I'd probably make your view a `LinearLayout` or just a `FrameLayout`, and expose the `RadioGroup` as a property so code can interact with it. And add any `RadioGroup` XML attributes to your custom view

Comment: Yes I think this is the only way, also looking at the answer from Tenfour04 below. I can confirm it is working. Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess at a strategy that might work. I didn't try it, and there might be some kinks that need to be worked out.

Make your class extend LinearLayout instead of RadioGroup. After all, your XML template is a LinearLayout.

In your class, override `addView()` so if the child view is a RadioButton, you add it to the child RadioGroup instead of the top level LinearLayout. Luckily, RadioGroup is also a LinearLayout, so the LayoutParams should be transferrable.

The theory here is that when your XML that contains your class is being inflated, it will start calling `addView` for the nested RadioButtons, and your code will intercept and pass these views down into the RadioGroup to be grandchildren instead.

```
class LabelRadioGroup(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : LinearLayout(context, attrs)
{
    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.compound_label_radiogroup, this)
    }

    private val radioGroup: RadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup)

    override fun addView(child: View, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams) {
        if (child is RadioButton) {
            radioGroup.addView(child, -1, params)
            return
        }
        super.addView(child, index, params)
    }

    // Add RadioGroup pass-through functions that you need, for example:

    fun setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) =
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)

    
}
```

Comment: I would have hoped there was a way to keep all the RadioGroup functions without overriding them, but it seems there is no way to do that. I can confirm your example is working and does solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: @Jordy the problem is if your custom view is a RadioGroup, but you also have a second internal RadioGroup that's meant to be the "real" one, you'd still have to delegate all the calls on your view to that second RadioGroup instance anyway. The alternative is exposing the internal RadioGroup so it can be interacted with directly, and your custom view is basically "a thing that has a RadioGroup" (which is closer to the *compound control* idea https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-components#compound)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply in LinearLayout as below, It will produce same output as your required end result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio button 1" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Radio button 2" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this makes it fixed to these 2 radiobuttons but it needs to be a reusable control, which may have different radiobuttons depending on the usage. I will edit the question to clarify this more clearly.

Comment: I still can't understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create a reusable custom radio group which includes a label on top.